# omniauth-facebook cannnot get email address

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, devise, omniauth, omniauth-facebook

I created new Rails App and install Devise and omniauth-facebook gem.

And setting my Facebook App, as testing environment.

So, I logged in via facebook and signed up my new Rails app, but request.env did not contain email address.info.

this is returned request.env['omniauth.auth']

```
{
   "provider" => "facebook",
   "uid" => "xxxxxxxxxxxx",
   "info" => {
         "name" => "xxxxxxx",
        "image" => "http://graph.facebook.com/xxx/picture"
    },
    "credentials" => {
             "token" => "tokenstring",
        "expires_at" => xxxxxxxxx,
           "expires" => true
    },
          "extra" => {
        "raw_info" => {
            "name" => "xxx xxxx",
              "id" => "xxxxxxxxx"
        }
    }
}
```

it racks request.env['omniauth.auth']['info']['email']

How can I get email address from facebook via oauth? Please anyone help me.

Rails ver is 4.2.3
Ruby ver is 2.2.2p95

This is Gem Versions

```
 omniauth (1.2.2)
 omniauth-facebook (2.0.1)
 devise (3.5.1)
```

config/initializers/devise.rb

```
  config.omniauth :facebook, 'appId', 'appSeacret', scope: 'email,public_profile'
```

app/controllers/omniauth_callbacks_controller.rb

```
  def all_provider
    user = User.from_omniauth(request.env['omniauth.auth'])
    if user.persisted?
      sign_in_and_redirect user
    else
      session['devise.user_attributes'] = user.attributes
      redirect_to new_user_registration_url
    end
  end

  alias_method :facebook, :all_provider
```

app/models/user.rb

```
def from_omniauth(auth)
  where(provider: auth.provider, uid: auth.uid).first_or_create do |user|
    user.email = auth.info.email
  end
end
```

**Add at 2015/7/11**

I retried same code with my old test facebook application, and COULD get full public_profile and email.

Are any restrictions added for new facebook app?? someone knows?

Answer (score 14):

I found the way to get email address myself.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog#v2_4

This doc says that

> Declarative Fields To try to improve performance on mobile networks,
>   Nodes and Edges in v2.4 requires that you explicitly request the
>   field(s) you need for your GET requests. For example, GET
>   /v2.4/me/feed no longer includes likes and comments by default, but
>   GET /v2.4/me/feed?fields=comments,likes will return the data. For more
>   details see the docs on how to request specific fields.

so, it need to write in config/initializers/devise.rb

```
  config.omniauth :facebook, 'app_id', 'app_secret',  scope: 'email', info_fields: 'email'
```

- `scope: 'email'` is default

not only scope, but also info_fields.

Comment: for me dont work, i dont know why, in my devise config have  config.omniauth :facebook, p.key, p.secret, scope: 'email', info_fields: 'email, name'  but when try to get email user omniauth[:info][:email], this is empty

Comment: Same issue exist for me

Comment: This doesn't work. I have everything place still many a time email is not returned from FaceOAuth