# Rails OmniAuth-Facebook and doesn't get email from FB

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook-graph-api, devise, omniauth, omniauth-facebook

I have a rails applications, that uses Devise to manage users, now i added OmniAuth to authorise Facebook login and that is the problem, facebook did not return emails.

Here is the data:

```
               Rails 4.2.4
               ruby 2.2.3p173 (2015-08-18 revision 51636) [x86_64-darwin15]
               Devise 2.4.8
               Omniauth-Facebook 2.4.8
               Facebook API 2.5
```

On my initialisers at devise.rb here is how i'm asking Facebok API for data:

```
config.omniauth :facebook, ENV["APP_ID"], ENV["APP_SECRET"], scope: 'email', info_fields: 'email, name', :image_size => 'normal'
```

But FB only send me the user name and the user profile pic but not the email.

i already visited this StackOverflow links:

[omniauth-facebook cannnot get email address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31337829/omniauth-facebook-cannnot-get-email-address)

[Facebook OAuth is not returning email in user info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31503090/facebook-oauth-is-not-returning-email-in-user-info)

[Omniauth Facebook not returning email and gender rails 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32859313/omniauth-facebook-not-returning-email-and-gender-rails-4)

[Ruby on Rails Omniauth facebook doesn't return email](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31954540/ruby-on-rails-omniauth-facebook-doesnt-return-email/31956381#31956381)

Comment: Growing number of Facebook users doesn't have email provided at all (signup on mobile) or decide not to give it to your app (through new permissions dialog). You have to work around it unfortunately

Comment: i'm trying with my own facebook account and authorized it but still did not work

Comment: Did you try to install the omniauth gem as well ? You need both the omniauth and omniauth-facebook gem.

Comment: @AlexanderLuna yep, i have already tried add both gems